# ListBox does not fire MouseRightButtonUp event

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is there any particular reason why ListBox does not fire the MouseRightButtonUp event?

```
<ListBox x:Name="Users"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
             MouseRightButtonUp="MouseRightButtonUp" />
```

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115892/right-click-on-a-listbox-in-a-silverlight-4-app

Comment: @kayboardP not really. I can use the MouseRightButtonDown event, which is fired, but not MouseRightButtonUp.

Comment: Hi.I guess the problem is like Murven said, that the RightButtonUp event is handled by another control and is not getting to the ListBox. But if you add a MouseRightButtonDownHandler and just set e.handled = true in this handler, the MouseRightButtonUpHandler is called... Xaml:<ListBox x:Name="Users" MouseRightButtonDown="downHandler" MouseRightButtonUp="upHandler"...> CodeBehind: private void downHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

Comment: @TerenceJackson interesting. I'll test this and let you know.

Comment: @TerenceJackson yes, it's works. That's interesting. You should have added this as an answer.

Comment: @TerenceJackson yes, defiantly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the answer taken from my previous comment ;)

I guess the problem is like Murven said, that the RightButtonUp event is handled by another control and is not getting to the ListBox. But if you add a MouseRightButtonDownHandler and just set e.handled = true in this handler, the MouseRightButtonUpHandler is called...

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Users" MouseRightButtonDown="downHandler" MouseRightButtonUp="upHandler"...>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void downHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { e.Handled = true; }
```

BR,

TJ

Answer (score 0):

When a routed event is not fired in your control it means a control which is deeper in the visual tree is "eating" the event by marking it as handled in the event chain. In your case I suspect it is the ScrollViewer inside the ListBox eating the event.

Comment: Probably. Is there any suggestion for a solution?